# Can't Style An Image Inside A Div?

Tags: html, css

I have an `<img>` tag inside a `<div>` tag and they both have classes but when I try to style the img class inside of CSS, it doesn't work? Also, whenever I try to set the div class to an id and change it in CSS, it disappears. Any help?

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/mmfm4vee/

**HTML:**

```
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script src="js/loading.js"></script>

    <!--Stylesheet Links-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" text="text/css" href="css/style.css">

    <link rel="stylesheet" text="text/css" href="css/font-awesome.min.css">

    <!--Font Links-->
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
    <!--Website Header-->
    <div id="header">
        <div class="steam-info">
            <img class="steam-avatar" src="<?$steamprofile['avatar'];?>">
            <ul>
                <li><a href=#></a>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

**CSS:**

```
/* Website Header */
#header {
    background:rgb(28,28,28);
    width:100%;
    height:60px;
    position:absolute;
    box-shadow:0px 0px 8px 2px black;
    border-top:3px solid rgb(235,50,50);
    z-index:99999999;
    left:0px;
    top:0px;
}

.steam-info {
    background:rgb(50,50,50);
    border-left:3px solid rgb(235,50,50);;
    width:160px;
    height:40px;
    position:absolute;
    z-index:999999999;
    top:10px;
    left:1160px;
}

.steam-info a {
    display:block;
    color:rgb(255,255,255);
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    font-size:30px;
}

.steam-avatar {
    width:30px;
    height:30px;
}
```

Comment: It's hard to tell with your example as it's not replicable. From what I can tell, it's because your class `.steam-info` is `position:absolute`. I can't see clearly though, as you're loading dynamic images. These images cannot be reproduced, so the problem cannot be replicated. For CSS issues, please provide raw HTML with images that are public. Your question is also not clear; what is the *intended* behaviour? Please create a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), and others will find it much easier to help you.

Comment: Ok I hope that is enough i kind of fixed it. If my question wasn't very clear I just want to be able to center the image in the top right. Also, the only reason your don't see an image is because it's set up to a steam database that takes your account's picture and puts it there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking through the code, there appears to be no problem adjusting the style of the image when using an image through placehold.it.

I simply replaced `<?$steamprofile['avatar'];?>` with `http://placehold.it/200` and was able to both see the image, and succesfully change the way it displays with simple changes to:

```
.steam-avatar {
    width: 100px;
    height: 30px;
}
```

Therefor, I conclude that the problem is with the way your PHP script grabs the image from Steam.

Updated code with that slight change can be found [here](https://jsfiddle.net/Obsidian_Age/szpys9nn/).

Sorry this can't be of more help, but the code appears to be functioning correctly aside from the image coming through from Steam.